# Django Class Based View with get_queryset()

Tags: django

I would like to use `get_queryset()` with Class Based View but I don't overcome to display variables in my template.

The function is very simple :

```
class MyClassView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView) :

    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    model = Foo

    def get_queryset(self) :

        foo = Foo.objects.order_by('-id')
        bar = foo.filter(Country=64)
        return foo, bar
```

And my template :

```
<table style="width:120%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in foo %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ foo.id }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
<br></br>
<table style="width:120%">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in bar %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ bar.id }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I have to use `Context` dictionary ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `get_queryset` method for a `ListView` should return a single queryset (or list of items). If you want to add another variable to the context, then override `get_context_data` as well:

```
class MyClassView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView) :

    template_name = 'my_template.html'
    model = Foo

    def get_queryset(self) :
        queryset = Foo.objects.order_by('-id')
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyClassView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bar_list'] = context['foo_list'].filter(Country=64)
        return context
```

In the template for a `ListView`, you access the queryset with `object_list` or `<model>_list` (e.g. `foo_list`), [unless you set context_object_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts). I've used `bar_list` in `get_context_data` to be consistent with that. You need to change the template to loop through `{% for item in foo_list %}` and `{% for item in bar_list %}`

Comment: by OP logic may be `context['bars'] = self.get_queryset().filter(Country=64)`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't overcome to display foo in my template and I don't understand why ?

Comment: You're probably using the wrong variable in your template then. It's harder to help when you've used made up variable names like `foo` and `bar` in your view and template.

Comment: @BearBrown I've removed the repeated `Foo.objects`, but fetched the queryset from the context instead of calling `get_queryset` again.

Comment: I'm just getting an issue : `Exception Type: KeyError at /Foo/List/ Exception Value: 'foo_list' in context['bar_list'] = context['foo_list'].filter(Country=64)`

Comment: I think the above code should work, and the issue might be you using made-up variable names. If you add `print(context)` on the previous line you might be able to spot your mistake when you see the context keys.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1) `get_queryset` returns, well, a `QuerySet`. You're returning a tuple. 
2) `Listview` by default passes the query set into a template variable called `object_list`

However, you can do this all in the template with zero overrides to methods.

```
{% for item in object_list %}
    {% if item.country == 64 %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
    </tr>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

That would iterate over all items `Foo` and only print ones that have `country == 64` (If that's a foreign key, you'd need to construct the query differently.)

If for some reason you must do this in the view, you'll need to tweak by `get_queryset` and `get_context` to have two different object lists.